# How to programming efficiently without "for" in software R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to progamming more efficiently without one "for", but when i remove one loop the time increases.

What i'm doing wrong?

Please, don't focus in result, because these numbers are symbolics and i have more code inside the "for". I need to improve the line: "problem line".

attempt 1 takes 1.7s

attempt 2 takes 9s

```
nSteps = 200; p=0.45

v = data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=nSteps+1,ncol=nSteps+1))
v[nSteps+1,] <- rep(0.2,nSteps+1)

check = data.frame(matrix(15,nrow=nSteps+1,ncol=nSteps+1))

#################
### attempt 1 ###
    #################

   for ( m in nSteps:0){
    for (n in 1:(m+1)){
        hold = (1-p)*v[m+1,n]+p*v[m+1,n+1] #### problem line
        v[m,n] = ifelse(check[m,n]>=0,max(check[m,n],hold),max(hold,0))
    # more code here...     
    }
}

#################
### attempt 2 ###
    #################

seq1 = 1:nSteps
seq2 = 2:(nSteps+1)
for ( m in (nSteps:1)){
    vec = (1-p)*v[m+1,seq1]+p*v[m+1,seq2] ##### problem line
    v[m,]<-c(t(vec),0)
    # more code here... 
}
```

Comment: It is a myth that all for-loops are slow in R. Just removing the loop won't speed up your code. The slowdown usually comes from memory allocation, not the control structure itself. In fact, loops may be faster for many operations if you preallocate memory. It all depends on the specifics of your operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case, if my code was only like above, the best way is using two loops or I can do something better?

I would like improve those 1.7s.

Comment: OK... I'm not focusing on the result. I'm focusing on the process. WHAT precisely is the process? and the goal? .... defined in natural language?

Comment: I changed my object data.frame to a data.matrix and the results are pretty good, like Carlos Santillan said bellow. 

Thanks for your help and I'll study more about "memory allocation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at this, and it seems that the performance of this can be improved by changing your data.frame to a data.matrix.
In general Matrix performs much better than Data Frames, review the following

https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/7-1-data-types.html#matrix

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish...

For example the following operations ( Scalar multiplied by matrix, multiplied by vector) 
are significantly faster using Data Matrix

```
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6,c = 7:9)
V <- data.frame(a = 10:12)

dm <- data.matrix(DF)
dv <- data.matrix(V)

DFl <- list()
dml <- list()

system.time(
  for ( m in 2500:1){
    DFl[[m]] <-( 3 * DF * V[,1])
  }
)

system.time(
  for ( m in 2500:1){
    dml[[m]] <- (  3 * dm * dv[1])
  }
)
```

First case performance if considerably faster by changing to matrix (about 3 times faster).

Running the following returns

Attempt 1

user  system elapsed

2.11    0.00    2.11

Attempt 1a

user  system elapsed

0.69    0.00    0.69

Attempt 2

user  system elapsed

8.60    0.00    8.63

Attempt 3
   user  system elapsed

0.02    0.00    0.02

Compare Results

TRUE

```
library(compare)
nSteps = 200; p=0.45

v = data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=nSteps+2,ncol=nSteps+2))

#CS added extra row, looks like the logic was assuming that out of range DF returns NULL and errors subscript out of bounds on data.matrix

v[nSteps+1,] <- rep(0.2,nSteps+1)
vtemp <- v

check = data.frame(matrix(15,nrow=nSteps+1,ncol=nSteps+1))


#################
### attempt 1 ###
#################
v<- vtemp 
system.time(
for ( m in nSteps:0){
  for (n in 1:(m+1)){
    hold = (1-p)*v[m+1,n]+p*v[m+1,n+1] #### problem line
    v[m,n] = ifelse(check[m,n]>=0,max(check[m,n],hold),max(hold,0))
    # more code here...     
  }
}
)
v1 <- v

#################
### attempt 1a ###
#################
v<- vtemp 
check2 = matrix(15,nrow=nSteps+1,ncol=nSteps+1)
v1a <- data.matrix(v) 
system.time(
  for ( m in nSteps:0){
    for (n in 1:(m+1)){
      hold = (1-p)*v1a[m+1,n]+p*v1a[m+1,n+1] #### problem line
      v1a[m,n] = ifelse(check[m,n]>=0,max(check[m,n],hold),max(hold,0))
      # more code here...     
    }
  }
)

v1a <- data.frame(v1a)
compare(v1,v1a)



#################
### attempt 2 ###
#################

v = data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=nSteps+1,ncol=nSteps+1))
v[nSteps+1,] <- rep(0.2,nSteps+1)
vtemp <- v


seq1 = 1:nSteps
seq2 = 2:(nSteps+1)
system.time(
for ( m in (nSteps:1)){
  vec = (1-p)*v[m+1,seq1]+p*v[m+1,seq2] ##### problem line
  v[m,]<-c(t(vec),0)
  # more code here... 
}
)
v2 <- v

#################
### attempt 3 ###
#################

seq1 = 1:nSteps
seq2 = 2:(nSteps+1)

v3 <- data.matrix(vtemp)
#note Matrix index is 0 based
system.time(
  for ( m in (nSteps:0)){
    vec = (1-p) * v3[m+1,seq1] + p * v3[m+1,seq2] ##### problem line
    v3[m,]<-c(t(vec),0)
    # more code here... 
  }
)
v3 <- data.frame(v3)

compare(v2,v3)
```

Comment: Really really thanks. 

I changed my object like u said and this helped me a lot. Now, the performance is very faster (1.7s to 0.3s).